# How the get the number bigger than the average number in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have three tables in my db which were created via the following declarations:

```
create table employee (
id serial primary key,
name varchar (20) not null,
surname varchar(30) not null,
registration_date date default current_date);

create table task (
id serial primary key,
title varchar (50) not null,
created_date date default current_date,
empl_id integer references employee (id) on cascade update,
cat_id integer references category (id) on cascade update);

create table category (
id serial primary key,
name varchar (30) not null );
```

How ca I get the employee.id of employees who have the amount of tasks assigned to them more than the average amount of tasks assigned to employees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I've reduced your tables by deleting FOREIGN KEYS just for the sake of the question.

> ```
> create table task 
> (
> id serial primary key,
> title varchar (50) not null,
> created_date date default current_date,
> empl_id integer,
> cat_id integer
> );
>
> create table employee 
> (
> id serial primary key,
> name varchar (20) not null,
> surname varchar(30) not null,
> registration_date date default current_date
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into employee values
> (1, 'Emp1', 'SEmp1', now()),
> (2, 'Emp2', 'SEmp2', now()),
> (3, 'Emp3', 'SEmp3', now());
> ```

> ```
> insert into task values
> (1, 'Task1', now(), 1, 0),
> (2, 'Task2', now(), 1, 0),
> (3, 'Task3', now(), 1, 0),
> (4, 'Task4', now(), 2, 0),
> (5, 'Task5', now(), 2, 0),
> (6, 'Task6', now(), 3, 0);
> ```

I've used this query to calculate AVG():

> ```
> select avg(tasks) as average
> from   (select empl_id, count(*) as tasks from task group by empl_id) t1;
> ```
>
> ```
> |            average |
> | -----------------: |
> | 2.0000000000000000 |
> ```

Then I've used it to filter employees > AVG().

> ```
> select   empl_id, count(*) as tasks
> from     task
> group by empl_id
> having   count(*) > (select avg(tasks) as average
>                      from   (select   empl_id, count(*) as tasks 
>                              from     task 
>                              group by empl_id) t1);
> ```
>
> ```
> empl_id | tasks
> ------: | ----:
>       1 |     3
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=fd2d47b81630f237a401040f5bd8c5c9)*